# Top row won't change in my JQuery function when I swap table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery

My jquery function allows me to click on the UP arrow and it swaps rows in a table. I have ranking numbers in each of the rows. I can only get the clicked number to change. I want both numbers to swap. I know the value abovecnt isn't getting set correctlty. I just can't figure out how to get it. Right now it is just undefined.

http://jsfiddle.net/Thread7/2rmowem4/15/

```
$('.change-rank').click(function() {
var cnt = $(this).attr('cnt');                                                       
var direction = $(this).attr('data-direction'),
    $original = $(this).closest("tr"),
    $target = direction === "up" ? $original.prev() : $original.next();

if ( $target.length && direction === "up" ) {
    $original.insertBefore($target);
    abovecnt = $original.find('.ranky input[type="text"]').val();
    $('#rank_' + cnt).val(cnt-1);
    $('#rank_' + abovecnt).val(cnt);
    alert('abovecnt=' + abovecnt + '|cnt=' + cnt);      
}
else if( $target.length ) {
    $original.insertAfter($target);
}
});
```

I will want the down arrow to change the value also but atm I just want the up arrow to work.

Comment: Check this link out: http://www.safnet.com/writing/tech/2012/07/manipulating-table-rows-with-jquery.html# The script does exactly what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your HTML:

```
<input type='text' id='rank_1' value='4' class='ranky'>
```

You have a problem with this line:

```
abovecnt = $original.find('.ranky input[type="text"]').val();
```

Which should be:

```
abovecnt = $original.find('input[type="text"].ranky').val();
// As "id" attribute have to be unique, even better using this:
abovecnt = $('#rank_1').val();
```

Why is that?

Using  `.ranky input[type="text"]` (note the space between *ranky* and *input*) means, that you're looking for an `input type="text"` which is **inside** an element with `ranky` class (which is not).

Using `input[type="text"].ranky` you refer to input field with `ranky` class - as should be.

---

Althought the rest of your code works correctly, you should **NOT** use the same `id` attribute for more than one element. [`id-selector`](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) have to be unique. I would also suggest you to not use custom attributes like `cnt`. There's a `data` attribute to store arbitrary data associated with the matched elements. Eg:

```
<a href='#' class='change-rank' data-direction='down' data-cnt=4>
```

And then access it using **[jQuery's data() method](http://api.jquery.com/data/)**:

```
var cnt = $(this).data('cnt');
```

Comment: Thank you.  I modified it and now works well - http://jsfiddle.net/Thread7/6r63nLm4/55/